# Subir a github desde consola git

Tags: git, github, repositorio

Buenas estoy tratando de subir un proyecto bastante pequeño a git hub
por consola de gi. Creo el repositorio, agrego todo con `git add .` luego hago los commit y todo bien.

Voy a mi cuenta de github, creo un repositorio, le doy nombre y luego, una vez creado, copio el enlace de `git remote add origin https://github.com/` que sale en: …or push an existing repository from the command line.

Lo copio en la consola por supuesto de git y bien. Luego vuelvo a github, actualizo o refresco página y se queda en la misma página. No ha subido nada, y aunque borre el repositorio y cree otro, a la hora de subirlo me dice que ya existe, pero nunca veo subido los archivos.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio ¿podrías editar la pregunta y añadir en modo texto lo que te salió al hacer git push?

Comment: Hola me sucede lo mismo , lo hago todo como me manda Github y al final termina dandome esl sgt error. Podria alguien echarme una mano por favor ? [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5E62.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5E62.png)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pudo pasar es que te faltó cambiar el nombre de tu rama y hacer push (como lo sugiere GitHub) para que tu código se suba, prueba ejecutando las siguientes dos lineas (después de haber ejecutado: `git remote add ...`):

```
git branch -M main 
git push -u origin main
```

si aun así no se sube tu código a GitHub, comprueba si la url del repositorio remoto está correcta ejecutando la siguiente linea:

```
git remote -v
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Tienes enlazado tu repositorio local con github?

Si no es así, puedes probar con `git remote add origin [URL de tu repositorio en GitHub]`

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente, ya tengas clonado el repositorio.

Prueba con:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Buenas el problema es que cuando pincho al repositorio está en la misma página donde me dice desde donde lo queremos importar pero no llega a estar nunca en GitHub no tiene nada. O un. La verdad que es un poco desesperante

Comment: Es un repositorio privado o público?